# How to get relational data with REST API

Tags: phpmyadmin, relational-database

I'm using this RESTFUL API: https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api
I've used it in simple apps succesfully.
Now I'm setting up a relational database. With phpmyadmin I can write queries to get relational data. So I think the relational structure is OK. But I want to use this REST API to retrieve this data. 
Can anyone help me with the syntax. I've tried the documentation on this site, but with no success.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and someone will be willing to help. You won't get a lot of traction in the question if you are asking people to write the code. There is a tutorial however to get you started. https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/

Comment: I have 3 tables: members, projects and subscribed. The last table is to bring together members who subscribe to a project. The relation is a many to many: one member can subscribe to many projects and vice versa: one projects can have many members. 
Now I want to use the rest api I mentioned. Following the documentation I write this code:
api.php/subscribed?include=members,projects&filter=id,eq,1

Comment: This should give me members and projects who are related to the subscribed table with id=1.
The result I get is only a list of the subscribed table. The syntax is wrong I think.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have the required foreign key constraints defined as described [here](http://alvinalexander.com/mysql/mysql-foreign-key-in-mysql-innodb-constraint).

But feel free to open an issue on [Github](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api/issues) as I am happy to help you.

NB: I am the author of that script.